# STM32F303 code gets stuck in SysTick Exception Handler

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, cortex-m

I am working with a STM32F303 microcontroller with a Nucleo board and my code gets stuck in the `SysTick_Handler` routine of the startup_stm32f303xe.s file. (My code is based on an example Nucleo project, but rebuilt from scratch for learning purposes).

[This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/212194/stm32f7-gets-stuck-in-external-interrupt-callback-function) suggests that I need to set the Systick Interrupt to higher priority, which I did and doesn't fix the problem. [This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331650/whats-the-difference-between-setting-systick-interrupt-in-nvic-and-using-it-as) suggests that the Systick Exception occurs when the system timer reaches 0... but I don't think I am using the system timer in my code.

In debug view with some breakpoints, I can see that the code executes to the two GPIO_TogglePin functions, after which it goes into the exception handler.

How can I prevent the program from causing the Systick Exception?

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {

    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    LED2_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED2_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(LED2_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(LED2_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
    // Also tried HAL_InitTick(0);

    while(1) {

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED2_GPIO_PORT, LED2_PIN);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8);

        // Project code
    }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

    /* HSI Oscillator already ON after system reset, activate PLL with HSI as source */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
    }

    /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
 clocks dividers */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK
        | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ST HAL requires the systick for operation.
It increments the system tick you can use via `HAL_GetTick()`, it is incremented in the `SysTick_Handler()` via `HAL_IncTick();`.
It will be configured by `HAL_SYSTICK_Config` somewhere in the HAL.

**You don't get stuck there.** It just gets called every 1 ms.

If you do get stuck in the systick handler, there could be something wrong with the vector table. Eg: the address for `SysTick_Handler` at the position for something else.

Check the IABR registers when halted.
*[4.2.6 Interrupt Active Bit Registers.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/DUI0552A_cortex_m3_dgug.pdf)*

Comment: Yep, turns out I was missing the SysTick_Handler() implementation. Adding the Handler function with `HAL_IncTick();` solves the "problem". Thanks!

Comment: HAL doesn't requre `SysTick`, it requires a a working `HAL_GetTick()` that can somehow figure out how many milliseconds did elapse since the program was started. `HAL_InitTick()` must be overridden if `SysTick` is not used.